# npm ERR! cb() never called! when doing npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to `npm install` and I have `npm ERR! cb() never called!` error,

this is the full error log: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kopax/3b627be39a50cf0a6bea6f20f7d179b2/raw/7448fb398a713e76620f138f7e7337eadb88f052/npm-error.log

What is breaking map project?

Answer (score 0):

In the message you posted through the link that you provide, at the end I found this message:

```
 65450 error cb() never called!
 65451 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
 65452 error <https://npm.community>
```

So, I believe you need to ask about this to npm community.

Comment: I don't use npm very frequently, but if I had your problem I probably would try starting here - https://npm.community